# Can I use sxhkd to bind to keycodes?

Tags: configuration, window-manager, automation

Is there a way to bind hotkeys in sxhkd using the keycodes, rather than the keysyms?

Answer (score 1):

The manual of sxhkd mentions nothing about the possibility of using keycodes rather than keysyms, so you likely cannot use keycodes.